# Best way to install from a stand-alone network

Tags: ros, installation, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been having issues installing electric on systems that are deployed to a network that does not have any internet access. I've had limited success using rosinstall on a system that does have internet access to checkout the full install, installing rosinstall on the machines behind the network and then coming up with a custom rosinstall file pointing to both the ros and stacks directories.

However this build does not always work. Just wondering if there's an easy way that given I have all the source code, how do I build the ros core system manually? I managed to get the environment variables setup and build rospack, but couldn't proceed from there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12950/best-way-to-install-from-a-stand-alone-network/) by [venabled](https://answers.ros.org/users/951/venabled/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-02-08**:
Which Linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're on Ubuntu and you only need released packages you can pull all the debian packages needed onto a single CD and install them using apt-cdrom. Or if you can transport a computer between the internal and external networks you can setup an apt-mirror as @Mac suggests.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even once you've installed the source, some of the builds pull more code (`mongodb`, for example, downloads some stuff during the `make`); that will tend to get in your way.

One idea: download and build everything you need on a machine with internet access (say, to `~/ros`), and then just copy it over to the other machines. Because you built first, all the internet-access-requiring things will be sorted out.

The more-general solution involves an `apt` mirror, if you're on Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1